# Should changing a model's intercept change its Precision and Recall?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression

For simplicity's sake -- just setting up a very basic logistic regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve, precision_recall_curve, classification_report

train_grad_des =  SGDClassifier(alpha=alpha_optimum, l1_ratio=l1_optimum, loss='log')
train_grad_des.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

For analysis, creating an array of `score_y` for predicted probabilities

```
score_y = train_grad_des.predict_proba(test_x)

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(test_y, score_y[:,1], pos_label=1)
```

If I set `train_grad_des.intercept_ = 100`, will that change the probabilities returned by `train_grad_des.predict_proba(test_x)`?

It seems like the probabilities should not change, they would just all be moved 'over' in one direction. And if the returned probabilities remain unchanged, shouldn't precision and recall at various thresholds remain unchanged as well?

I've been testing this with a model, and am finding that the precision and recall are drastically changed when I alter the intercept, but it's not clear to me if this should happen, and if it should, why it does.

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't the probabilities change? If we peel back some layers and look at the model being fit (binary logistic regression with one covariate):

`logit(p(y = 1|x)) = alpha + beta*x`

Where `logit` is the log odds in favor of being in class 1, that is:

`logit(p(Y=1)) = log( p(Y=1)/p(Y=0) )`

You can interpret `alpha`, the intercept, by itself as the prior probability of belonging to a certain class. So if you change `alpha` you can expect to change the log odds in favor of being in class 1.

Another way to look at it:

`p(y=1|x) = 1 / (1 + e^(-(alpha + beta*x)))`

Clearly if I change `alpha` my probabilities will change.